# Как перезагрузить страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать перезагрузку страницы на jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это должно работать на всех браузерах даже без `jQuery`:

```
location.reload();
```

Answer (score -1):

На HTML: (в "content" через количество секунд, "URL" куда редирект)

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=http://google.ru/">
```

На JavaScript (535 вариантов):

```
location = location
location = location.href
location = window.location
location = self.location
location = window.location.href
location = self.location.href
location = location['href']
location = window['location']
location = window['location'].href
location = window['location']['href']
location = window.location['href']
location = self['location']
location = self['location'].href
location = self['location']['href']
location = self.location['href']
location.assign(location)
location.replace(location)
window.location.assign(location)
window.location.replace(location)
self.location.assign(location)
self.location.replace(location)
location['assign'](location)
location['replace'](location)
window.location['assign'](location)
window.location['replace'](location)
window['location'].assign(location)
window['location'].replace(location)
window['location']['assign'](location)
window['location']['replace'](location)
self.location['assign'](location)
self.location['replace'](location)
self['location'].assign(location)
self['location'].replace(location)
self['location']['assign'](location)
self['location']['replace'](location)
location.href = location
location.href = location.href
location.href = window.location
location.href = self.location
location.href = window.location.href
location.href = self.location.href
location.href = location['href']
location.href = window['location']
location.href = window['location'].href
location.href = window['location']['href']
location.href = window.location['href']
location.href = self['location']
location.href = self['location'].href
location.href = self['location']['href']
location.href = self.location['href']
location.assign(location.href)
location.replace(location.href)
window.location.assign(location.href)
window.location.replace(location.href)
self.location.assign(location.href)
self.location.replace(location.href)
location['assign'](location.href)
location['replace'](location.href)
window.location['assign'](location.href)
window.location['replace'](location.href)
window['location'].assign(location.href)
window['location'].replace(location.href)
window['location']['assign'](location.href)
window['location']['replace'](location.href)
self.location['assign'](location.href)
self.location['replace'](location.href)
self['location'].assign(location.href)
self['location'].replace(location.href)
self['location']['assign'](location.href)
self['location']['replace'](location.href)
window.location = location
window.location = location.href
window.location = window.location
window.location = self.location
window.location = window.location.href
window.location = self.location.href
window.location = location['href']
window.location = window['location']
window.location = window['location'].href
window.location = window['location']['href']
window.location = window.location['href']
window.location = self['location']
window.location = self['location'].href
window.location = self['location']['href']
window.location = self.location['href']
location.assign(window.location)
location.replace(window.location)
window.location.assign(window.location)
window.location.replace(window.location)
self.location.assign(window.location)
self.location.replace(window.location)
location['assign'](window.location)
location['replace'](window.location)
window.location['assign'](window.location)
window.location['replace'](window.location)
window['location'].assign(window.location)
window['location'].replace(window.location)
window['location']['assign'](window.location)
window['location']['replace'](window.location)
self.location['assign'](window.location)
self.location['replace'](window.location)
self['location'].assign(window.location)
self['location'].replace(window.location)
self['location']['assign'](window.location)
self['location']['replace'](window.location)
self.location = location
self.location = location.href
self.location = window.location
self.location = self.location
self.location = window.location.href
self.location = self.location.href
self.location = location['href']
self.location = window['location']
self.location = window['location'].href
self.location = window['location']['href']
self.location = window.location['href']
self.location = self['location']
self.location = self['location'].href
self.location = self['location']['href']
self.location = self.location['href']
location.assign(self.location)
location.replace(self.location)
window.location.assign(self.location)
window.location.replace(self.location)
self.location.assign(self.location)
self.location.replace(self.location)
location['assign'](self.location)
location['replace'](self.location)
window.location['assign'](self.location)
window.location['replace'](self.location)
window['location'].assign(self.location)
window['location'].replace(self.location)
window['location']['assign'](self.location)
window['location']['replace'](self.location)
self.location['assign'](self.location)
self.location['replace'](self.location)
self['location'].assign(self.location)
self['location'].replace(self.location)
self['location']['assign'](self.location)
self['location']['replace'](self.location)
window.location.href = location
window.location.href = location.href
window.location.href = window.location
window.location.href = self.location
window.location.href = window.location.href
window.location.href = self.location.href
window.location.href = location['href']
window.location.href = window['location']
window.location.href = window['location'].href
window.location.href = window['location']['href']
window.location.href = window.location['href']
window.location.href = self['location']
window.location.href = self['location'].href
window.location.href = self['location']['href']
window.location.href = self.location['href']
location.assign(window.location.href)
location.replace(window.location.href)
window.location.assign(window.location.href)
window.location.replace(window.location.href)
self.location.assign(window.location.href)
self.location.replace(window.location.href)
location['assign'](window.location.href)
location['replace'](window.location.href)
window.location['assign'](window.location.href)
window.location['replace'](window.location.href)
window['location'].assign(window.location.href)
window['location'].replace(window.location.href)
window['location']['assign'](window.location.href)
window['location']['replace'](window.location.href)
self.location['assign'](window.location.href)
self.location['replace'](window.location.href)
self['location'].assign(window.location.href)
self['location'].replace(window.location.href)
self['location']['assign'](window.location.href)
self['location']['replace'](window.location.href)
self.location.href = location
self.location.href = location.href
self.location.href = window.location
self.location.href = self.location
self.location.href = window.location.href
self.location.href = self.location.href
self.location.href = location['href']
self.location.href = window['location']
self.location.href = window['location'].href
self.location.href = window['location']['href']
self.location.href = window.location['href']
self.location.href = self['location']
self.location.href = self['location'].href
self.location.href = self['location']['href']
self.location.href = self.location['href']
location.assign(self.location.href)
location.replace(self.location.href)
window.location.assign(self.location.href)
window.location.replace(self.location.href)
self.location.assign(self.location.href)
self.location.replace(self.location.href)
location['assign'](self.location.href)
location['replace'](self.location.href)
window.location['assign'](self.location.href)
window.location['replace'](self.location.href)
window['location'].assign(self.location.href)
window['location'].replace(self.location.href)
window['location']['assign'](self.location.href)
window['location']['replace'](self.location.href)
self.location['assign'](self.location.href)
self.location['replace'](self.location.href)
self['location'].assign(self.location.href)
self['location'].replace(self.location.href)
self['location']['assign'](self.location.href)
self['location']['replace'](self.location.href)
location['href'] = location
location['href'] = location.href
location['href'] = window.location
location['href'] = self.location
location['href'] = window.location.href
location['href'] = self.location.href
location['href'] = location['href']
location['href'] = window['location']
location['href'] = window['location'].href
location['href'] = window['location']['href']
location['href'] = window.location['href']
location['href'] = self['location']
location['href'] = self['location'].href
location['href'] = self['location']['href']
location['href'] = self.location['href']
location.assign(location['href'])
location.replace(location['href'])
window.location.assign(location['href'])
window.location.replace(location['href'])
self.location.assign(location['href'])
self.location.replace(location['href'])
location['assign'](location['href'])
location['replace'](location['href'])
window.location['assign'](location['href'])
window.location['replace'](location['href'])
window['location'].assign(location['href'])
window['location'].replace(location['href'])
window['location']['assign'](location['href'])
window['location']['replace'](location['href'])
self.location['assign'](location['href'])
self.location['replace'](location['href'])
self['location'].assign(location['href'])
self['location'].replace(location['href'])
self['location']['assign'](location['href'])
self['location']['replace'](location['href'])
window['location'] = location
window['location'] = location.href
window['location'] = window.location
window['location'] = self.location
window['location'] = window.location.href
window['location'] = self.location.href
window['location'] = location['href']
window['location'] = window['location']
window['location'] = window['location'].href
window['location'] = window['location']['href']
window['location'] = window.location['href']
window['location'] = self['location']
window['location'] = self['location'].href
window['location'] = self['location']['href']
window['location'] = self.location['href']
location.assign(window['location'])
location.replace(window['location'])
window.location.assign(window['location'])
window.location.replace(window['location'])
self.location.assign(window['location'])
self.location.replace(window['location'])
location['assign'](window['location'])
location['replace'](window['location'])
window.location['assign'](window['location'])
window.location['replace'](window['location'])
window['location'].assign(window['location'])
window['location'].replace(window['location'])
window['location']['assign'](window['location'])
window['location']['replace'](window['location'])
self.location['assign'](window['location'])
self.location['replace'](window['location'])
self['location'].assign(window['location'])
self['location'].replace(window['location'])
self['location']['assign'](window['location'])
self['location']['replace'](window['location'])
window['location'].href = location
window['location'].href = location.href
window['location'].href = window.location
window['location'].href = self.location
window['location'].href = window.location.href
window['location'].href = self.location.href
window['location'].href = location['href']
window['location'].href = window['location']
window['location'].href = window['location'].href
window['location'].href = window['location']['href']
window['location'].href = window.location['href']
window['location'].href = self['location']
window['location'].href = self['location'].href
window['location'].href = self['location']['href']
window['location'].href = self.location['href']
location.assign(window['location'].href)
location.replace(window['location'].href)
window.location.assign(window['location'].href)
window.location.replace(window['location'].href)
self.location.assign(window['location'].href)
self.location.replace(window['location'].href)
location['assign'](window['location'].href)
location['replace'](window['location'].href)
window.location['assign'](window['location'].href)
window.location['replace'](window['location'].href)
window['location'].assign(window['location'].href)
window['location'].replace(window['location'].href)
window['location']['assign'](window['location'].href)
window['location']['replace'](window['location'].href)
self.location['assign'](window['location'].href)
self.location['replace'](window['location'].href)
self['location'].assign(window['location'].href)
self['location'].replace(window['location'].href)
self['location']['assign'](window['location'].href)
self['location']['replace'](window['location'].href)
window['location']['href'] = location
window['location']['href'] = location.href
window['location']['href'] = window.location
window['location']['href'] = self.location
window['location']['href'] = window.location.href
window['location']['href'] = self.location.href
window['location']['href'] = location['href']
window['location']['href'] = window['location']
window['location']['href'] = window['location'].href
window['location']['href'] = window['location']['href']
window['location']['href'] = window.location['href']
window['location']['href'] = self['location']
window['location']['href'] = self['location'].href
window['location']['href'] = self['location']['href']
window['location']['href'] = self.location['href']
location.assign(window['location']['href'])
location.replace(window['location']['href'])
window.location.assign(window['location']['href'])
window.location.replace(window['location']['href'])
self.location.assign(window['location']['href'])
self.location.replace(window['location']['href'])
location['assign'](window['location']['href'])
location['replace'](window['location']['href'])
window.location['assign'](window['location']['href'])
window.location['replace'](window['location']['href'])
window['location'].assign(window['location']['href'])
window['location'].replace(window['location']['href'])
window['location']['assign'](window['location']['href'])
window['location']['replace'](window['location']['href'])
self.location['assign'](window['location']['href'])
self.location['replace'](window['location']['href'])
self['location'].assign(window['location']['href'])
self['location'].replace(window['location']['href'])
self['location']['assign'](window['location']['href'])
self['location']['replace'](window['location']['href'])
window.location['href'] = location
window.location['href'] = location.href
window.location['href'] = window.location
window.location['href'] = self.location
window.location['href'] = window.location.href
window.location['href'] = self.location.href
window.location['href'] = location['href']
window.location['href'] = window['location']
window.location['href'] = window['location'].href
window.location['href'] = window['location']['href']
window.location['href'] = window.location['href']
window.location['href'] = self['location']
window.location['href'] = self['location'].href
window.location['href'] = self['location']['href']
window.location['href'] = self.location['href']
location.assign(window.location['href'])
location.replace(window.location['href'])
window.location.assign(window.location['href'])
window.location.replace(window.location['href'])
self.location.assign(window.location['href'])
self.location.replace(window.location['href'])
location['assign'](window.location['href'])
location['replace'](window.location['href'])
window.location['assign'](window.location['href'])
window.location['replace'](window.location['href'])
window['location'].assign(window.location['href'])
window['location'].replace(window.location['href'])
window['location']['assign'](window.location['href'])
window['location']['replace'](window.location['href'])
self.location['assign'](window.location['href'])
self.location['replace'](window.location['href'])
self['location'].assign(window.location['href'])
self['location'].replace(window.location['href'])
self['location']['assign'](window.location['href'])
self['location']['replace'](window.location['href'])
self['location'] = location
self['location'] = location.href
self['location'] = window.location
self['location'] = self.location
self['location'] = window.location.href
self['location'] = self.location.href
self['location'] = location['href']
self['location'] = window['location']
self['location'] = window['location'].href
self['location'] = window['location']['href']
self['location'] = window.location['href']
self['location'] = self['location']
self['location'] = self['location'].href
self['location'] = self['location']['href']
self['location'] = self.location['href']
location.assign(self['location'])
location.replace(self['location'])
window.location.assign(self['location'])
window.location.replace(self['location'])
self.location.assign(self['location'])
self.location.replace(self['location'])
location['assign'](self['location'])
location['replace'](self['location'])
window.location['assign'](self['location'])
window.location['replace'](self['location'])
window['location'].assign(self['location'])
window['location'].replace(self['location'])
window['location']['assign'](self['location'])
window['location']['replace'](self['location'])
self.location['assign'](self['location'])
self.location['replace'](self['location'])
self['location'].assign(self['location'])
self['location'].replace(self['location'])
self['location']['assign'](self['location'])
self['location']['replace'](self['location'])
self['location'].href = location
self['location'].href = location.href
self['location'].href = window.location
self['location'].href = self.location
self['location'].href = window.location.href
self['location'].href = self.location.href
self['location'].href = location['href']
self['location'].href = window['location']
self['location'].href = window['location'].href
self['location'].href = window['location']['href']
self['location'].href = window.location['href']
self['location'].href = self['location']
self['location'].href = self['location'].href
self['location'].href = self['location']['href']
self['location'].href = self.location['href']
location.assign(self['location'].href)
location.replace(self['location'].href)
window.location.assign(self['location'].href)
window.location.replace(self['location'].href)
self.location.assign(self['location'].href)
self.location.replace(self['location'].href)
location['assign'](self['location'].href)
location['replace'](self['location'].href)
window.location['assign'](self['location'].href)
window.location['replace'](self['location'].href)
window['location'].assign(self['location'].href)
window['location'].replace(self['location'].href)
window['location']['assign'](self['location'].href)
window['location']['replace'](self['location'].href)
self.location['assign'](self['location'].href)
self.location['replace'](self['location'].href)
self['location'].assign(self['location'].href)
self['location'].replace(self['location'].href)
self['location']['assign'](self['location'].href)
self['location']['replace'](self['location'].href)
self['location']['href'] = location
self['location']['href'] = location.href
self['location']['href'] = window.location
self['location']['href'] = self.location
self['location']['href'] = window.location.href
self['location']['href'] = self.location.href
self['location']['href'] = location['href']
self['location']['href'] = window['location']
self['location']['href'] = window['location'].href
self['location']['href'] = window['location']['href']
self['location']['href'] = window.location['href']
self['location']['href'] = self['location']
self['location']['href'] = self['location'].href
self['location']['href'] = self['location']['href']
self['location']['href'] = self.location['href']
location.assign(self['location']['href'])
location.replace(self['location']['href'])
window.location.assign(self['location']['href'])
window.location.replace(self['location']['href'])
self.location.assign(self['location']['href'])
self.location.replace(self['location']['href'])
location['assign'](self['location']['href'])
location['replace'](self['location']['href'])
window.location['assign'](self['location']['href'])
window.location['replace'](self['location']['href'])
window['location'].assign(self['location']['href'])
window['location'].replace(self['location']['href'])
window['location']['assign'](self['location']['href'])
window['location']['replace'](self['location']['href'])
self.location['assign'](self['location']['href'])
self.location['replace'](self['location']['href'])
self['location'].assign(self['location']['href'])
self['location'].replace(self['location']['href'])
self['location']['assign'](self['location']['href'])
self['location']['replace'](self['location']['href'])
self.location['href'] = location
self.location['href'] = location.href
self.location['href'] = window.location
self.location['href'] = self.location
self.location['href'] = window.location.href
self.location['href'] = self.location.href
self.location['href'] = location['href']
self.location['href'] = window['location']
self.location['href'] = window['location'].href
self.location['href'] = window['location']['href']
self.location['href'] = window.location['href']
self.location['href'] = self['location']
self.location['href'] = self['location'].href
self.location['href'] = self['location']['href']
self.location['href'] = self.location['href']
location.assign(self.location['href'])
location.replace(self.location['href'])
window.location.assign(self.location['href'])
window.location.replace(self.location['href'])
self.location.assign(self.location['href'])
self.location.replace(self.location['href'])
location['assign'](self.location['href'])
location['replace'](self.location['href'])
window.location['assign'](self.location['href'])
window.location['replace'](self.location['href'])
window['location'].assign(self.location['href'])
window['location'].replace(self.location['href'])
window['location']['assign'](self.location['href'])
window['location']['replace'](self.location['href'])
self.location['assign'](self.location['href'])
self.location['replace'](self.location['href'])
self['location'].assign(self.location['href'])
self['location'].replace(self.location['href'])
self['location']['assign'](self.location['href'])
self['location']['replace'](self.location['href'])
location.reload()
location['reload']()
window.location.reload()
window['location'].reload()
window.location['reload']()
window['location']['reload']()
self.location.reload()
self['location'].reload()
self.location['reload']()
self['location']['reload']()
```